# System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException on overloading webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I am load testing my webservice

and get a
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException

when I use 10 threads to communicate to it (without any sleep in between) - basically testing 10 conenctions at a time - through a windows application

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/XXX/XXXService.asmx. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Why would this happen and how to best resolve it

Also is this the way how asp.net application will interact with it too - is threading the best way to do the load testing

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you might want to try using WCF for new web services development. Microsoft now considers ASMX web services to be "legacy technology", and suggests that all new development use WCF.

Next, you might want to find out what happened. The exception isn't lying to you. There was an HTTP protocol error. You could look at the network traffic using Fiddler, to see what the problem is.

You might also look in the server event log.

Comment: Can you help me with where I can find the server event log?

Comment: @soldieraman: Start Menu->Administrative Tools->Event Viewer. Look in the Application log.